# Error in creating stack header file. In C

Tags: c, stack

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
}node;

typedef struct Stack{
    node *top;
}stack;

bool push (stack *s , void *val)
{
    node *n;
    n = create_node (val);
    if (n)
    {
        n->next = s->top;
        s->top = n;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void* pop (stack *s)
{
    node *temp;
    void *x = NULL;
    if (s->top)
    {
        x = s->top->data;
        temp = s->top;
        s->top = s->top->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return x;
}

void* peek (stack *s)
{
    void *x = NULL;
    if (s->top)
        x = s->top->data;
    return x;
}

node* create_node (void *val)
{
    node *n;
    n = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    if (n)
    {
        n->data = val;
        n->next = NULL;
    }
    return n;
}

stack* create_stack (void)
{
    stack *s;
    s = (stack*) malloc (sizeof(stack));
    if (s)
        s->top = NULL;
    return s;
}
```

I tried to write a header file for stack in C. I included this header file in another program. I added the header file `#include"mystack.h"`

I think the error is somewhere in passing void pointer but I don't know how to debug it.

The stack gets created successfully but as I try to push or pop the code terminates. I can't seem to find the error.

The code for calling program is,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "mystack.h"

void main()
{
    stack *s = NULL;
    int *x;
    int val;
    bool res;

    s = create_stack ();
    printf ("Enter value to push : ");
    scanf ("%d" , val);
    res = push (s , &val);

    if (res)
    printf ("...PUSHED %d IN STACK...\n", *x);
    else
    printf ("...STACK OVERFLOW...\n");
    free(s->top);
    free(s);
}
```

The code stops after push operation is called.

Comment: From the implementation it looks like you have mixed up linked lists and stacks.

Comment: Please post your calling code that demonstrates the errors.

Comment: at push and pop you should check that s (the stack) is not null

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] and the verbatim copy of the errors you get. -- Is the source you show your **header file**? If so, it is an error to _implement_ the functions in it.

Comment: ``` #include <stdio.h> #include <stdbool.h> #include "mystack.h" void main() { stack *s = NULL; int *x; int val; bool res; s = create_stack (); printf ("Enter value to push : "); scanf ("%d" , val); //x = &val; res = push (s , &val); if (res) printf ("...PUSHED %d IN STACK...\n", *x); else printf ("...STACK OVERFLOW...\n"); free(s->top); free(s); if(!s) printf("stack freed"); } ``` I've added the code for the calling program. It creates the stack but it does exits as the push function is called. @KenY-N

Comment: @babon I've tried the linked implementation of stacks.

Comment: @arye It still doesn't work. I've created the stack before calling the push function so I guess it may not be the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the code there as it is too difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: @KenY-N I've edited my post. Please check.